# Need Manufacturer Drivers?

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I have a question and could use guidance on whether I ought explore installing drivers for my laptop: Dell E7470. Reason being the device manager shows a number of unknown devices (see screenshot).

[image: device manager]

However, the system is running fine without conflicts including running an external NVMe drive. looked into the driver pack from dell and it has numerous varieties (chipset and network expanded in the image). Is there a way to lookup the specific components via the serial number?

[image: driver pack chipset and network choices]

Windows 10 stock seems to provide sufficient functionality, however. Yet what would people do here?

Comment: Get the Dell Driver Update App and run that.  You should not have unidentified drivers as you do have.

Comment: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/latitude-e7470-ultrabook/drivers

Answer (score 0):

**To make sure all Dell drivers are installed, you may do an advanced driver restore and download all drivers for your device with the [Dell Command Update](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000177325/dell-command-update) application.** The utility will recognize your system configuration based on your service tag and install the manufacturer recommended drivers for your system.

**You should be able to research what precisely is not recognized properly via the hardware ID** found in the properties of the unknown device (right click the device in Device Manager). Probably Windows installed generic drivers. These make the components work in a basic way so the computer is usable, but might not include optimizations e.g. for improved power consumption.

Comment: On a prebuilt system it is not necessary to identify each driver, as the manufacturer provides driver packages on his support page or via a driver utility. It can be very misleading to suggest going that way first in your answer.

Comment: Since you can’t install drivers through Device Manager on current versions of Windows, the solution, is to use the Windows Update Catalog and search by device id

Comment: Thanks for your feedback mashuptwice, I moved the installation instructions upwards.